# Merging Tables : SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, merge

I am trying to use a merge statement to add to the manager_copy_d_cds table, the CDs from the 
original table. If there is a match, I will update the title and year. If not, I want to insert the data from the original table

The error I am receiving is this: 
**ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification**

```
merge into manager_copy_d_cds m using d_cds c  
on (m.cd_number = c.cd_number)  
when matched then update  
set (m.title = c.title, m.year = c.year)  
when not matched then insert   
values (c.cd_number, c.title, c.producer, c.year);
```

Table structure:

```
CD_NUMBER - NUMBER(5,0) - Not nullable   -  primary key(1)  
TITLE - VARCHAR2(50) - Not nullable  -   -  
PRODUCER - VARCHAR2(50) - Not nullable   -   -  
YEAR - VARCHAR2(4) - Not nullable    -   -
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You should take the sql-server tag out as you are using oracle.

Comment: Also post on your question your table structure.

Comment: What table is that? and the other one?

Comment: You don't need the parentheses around the `set` clause: `set m.title = c.title, m.year = c.year` - maybe that's confusing the parser.

Answer (score 0):

Logically you do not need to prefix the column names in the VALUES() clause with the table alias, nor the target column names in the UPDATE clause, so I suspect you can remove one or other or both.

Try:

```
merge into manager_copy_d_cds m using d_cds c  
on (m.cd_number = c.cd_number)  
when matched then update  
set (title = c.title, year = c.year)  
when not matched then insert   
values (cd_number, title, producer, year);
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at. [Oracle Merge Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF55042) which uses an example of

```
MERGE INTO bonuses D
   USING (SELECT employee_id, salary, department_id FROM employees
   WHERE department_id = 80) S
   ON (D.employee_id = S.employee_id)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET D.bonus = D.bonus + S.salary*.01
     DELETE WHERE (S.salary > 8000)
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT  (D.employee_id, D.bonus)
     VALUES (S.employee_id, S.salary*.01)
     WHERE (S.salary <= 8000);
```

Note this is near the insert statement: (Column names are specified)
**INSERT  (D.employee_id, D.bonus)**

Comment: Not a SQL Server question, Brent.